# How do I send contents to a container grid box when a link to a html file is clicked, I'd like to display the content in my grid box if possible

Tags: javascript, html, containers, css-grid, display

I'm not a web designer by any stretch, but I'm creating a website for a manual.  I have a sidebar menu and when you click a topic, I'd like to populate the text on the home page, next to the sidebar in the content box.  I used a 2 column grid but have no idea how to get anything sent to my "contents" section.  I've seen other sites do this, but maybe I took the wrong approach.

Looked for help on youtube, but couldn't find anything covering this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: if you see this on simple page then open Developer Tools and check how it is done. Might be java script hiding all and making just one DIV container visible without navigating.... it all depends on the specific goals and requirements :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.